# Serving Pregzipped Files If They Exisit

Tags: .htaccess

I have pregenerated gzipped files on my server. They're right next to their ungzipped counterparts, and the only difference is the .gz extension.

I'm trying to write some code in my .htaccess file so if the file request is a specific type of file, and the browser supports gzipped files, and the gzipped file exisits, then that file is served.

Unfortunately my code doesn't work and I'm having a hard time figuring out where I'm going wrong. Right now just the ungzipped file is being served.

What am I doing wrong?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(html|css|js|kml|csv)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}\.gz -f
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI} %{REQUEST_URI}.gz [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(html|css|js|kml|csv)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/$ /$1.gz [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).